# How to get Jsonobject from list in java?

Tags: java, json, list

I have two jsonobject which is in list. If I make new jsonobject and trying to get list in that it is giving me null.

Code is here below-

```
    private int isExisting(String pid, List profile, String size) throws JSONException {
       for (int i = 0; i < profile.size(); i++) {
           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(profile.get(i));
           log.info("--------------" + obj.toString());   //it is giving me an empty object but list contains two objects {"size":"M","id":11} and {"size":8,"id":19}
       }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe show the code that's calling your method and what you're passing into it.

Comment: Also could you post your sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this simple logic and it is working fine-

```
private int isExisting(String pid, List profile, String size) throws JSONException {
       for (int i = 0; i < profile.size(); i++) {
           JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) profile.get(i);
           log.info("--------------" + obj.toString());   
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this it worked

```
private void isExisting(String pid, List profile, String size) throws JSONException {
    for (int i = 0; i < profile.size(); i++) {
        if(profile.get(i)!=null) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(profile.get(i).toString());
            System.out.print("keys----------" + obj.toString());  
        }
    }
}

public void processList() {
    try {
        JSONObject objA= new JSONObject("{\n" +
                "      \"size\": \"M\",\n" +
                "      \"id\": 11\n" +
                "    }");
        JSONObject objB=new JSONObject("{\n" +
                "      \"size\": 8,\n" +
                "      \"id\": 19\n" +
                "    }");

        List<JSONObject> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(objA);
        list.add(objB);
        isExisting("",list,"");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```